# what is the difference between the past progressive form and simple past form in this sentence?

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-continuous

What is the difference between the past progressive form and simple past form in this sentence?

> He purchased it at ten times the price the owner **was asking** and carefully hid it in his house.

If I write "asked" instead of "was asking", is there any difference in nuance?

Comment: Do you understand the function of past progressive? What about this sentence confuses you?

Answer (score 0):

A person has an asking price.

*What are you asking for that car?*

**What was he asking for that price?**

It's almost an idiom. The **was asking suggests duration** to the amount the man wanted for the car.

They were asking $20.00 when I went to buy that car.

Comment: The OP was asking what was the difference in meaning between *was asking* and *asked*

Answer (score 0):

The simple and continuous forms of all verbs have their respective nuances and you should decide what you want the sentence to mean, and then choose the appropriate form:

All simple forms of the verb indicate an action as a whole - from start to finish.

B: I ride a bike. -> “ride” includes everything from getting on the bike at the start of the journey to getting off the bike at the end.

He asked for a price includes everything from thinking of the price to receiving the price.

The continuous form of the verb indicates

(i) an action that is/was/will be **(i)** incomplete and **(ii)** in progress **(iii)** at the time that is being referred to (it has started but it has not yet finished) ->

I will be/am/was/have been/had been riding a bike = I will be/am/was/have been/had been in the process of riding a bike but have not yet finished riding the bike at the time I am referring to.

Someone **is asking** for a price - they are in a process. They have started to ask for a price but, at the time referred to they have not stopped asking for that price,